# Find moment generating function with specified pdf

Tags: moment-generating-functions

$f(x) = 2x/c^2$, $0<x<c$

Integration of $2xe^{tx}/c^2$ between 0 and c gives the MGF;

$2e^{tc}/c$.

But it does not seem right. I cant use it to find expected value. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) with pameters $a=0$ and $b=c$.

By direct integration
$$
M_X(t)=\Bbb E(\mathrm e^{tX})=\frac{2}{c^2}\int_0^c x\,\mathrm e^{tx}\mathrm dx=\tfrac{2}{c^2}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\int_0^c \mathrm e^{tx}\mathrm dx\right)=\tfrac{2}{c^2}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\tfrac{\mathrm e^{ct}-1}{t}\right)=2\frac{\mathrm e^{ct}(ct-1)+1}{t^2c^2}
$$
and the Taylor expansion using the expansion for $\mathrm e^{ct}$  is 
$$
M_X(t)=1+\frac{2c}{3}t+\frac{c^2}{2}\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^3)=1+M_X'(0)t+M''_X(0)\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^3)
$$
and then $\Bbb E(X)=\frac{2c}{3}$

Comment: What's the MGF, and could you clarify how to calculate the E(X) from it. Is THE MGF I came up with wrong?

Comment: Yes you MGF is wrong. I've added the detail for the mean.

Comment: Are you missing an "x" inside the integration at second row of your calc, or am I wrong?

Comment: Do you mean with the $t$-derivative?

Comment: Yes exactly.  That row.

Comment: Observe that I've used the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) for differentiation under the integral sign $$\int_0^c \Big(x\,\mathrm e^{tx}\Big)\mathrm dx=\int_0^c \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\mathrm e^{tx}\right)\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\int_0^c \mathrm e^{tx}\mathrm dx\right)=\tfrac{2}{c^2}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\tfrac{\mathrm e^{ct}-1}{t}\right)$$

Comment: It’s very much possible to do it with integration by parts. The use of that theorem seems sneaky if you aren’t used to it.